# Filter first letters in a column - R

Tags: r, filter, data.table

Hi I have this dataset;

```
dt <- data.table(ID = c(1,2,3, 4, 1),
                 diagnosis = c("A1053", "A10534", "A1034", "A1400", "B1008"))
```

I want to only choose codes that begin with "A105" (so in this case A1053, A10534) and the code B1008. How can I in data.table make this filter?

```
dt[diagnosis == ??]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `grep` and use `|` for or to also include the B letter like this:

```r
library(data.table)
dt[grep("A105|B1008", diagnosis),]
#>    ID diagnosis
#> 1:  1     A1053
#> 2:  2    A10534
#> 3:  1     B1008
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: what if I have a third varibale called type = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "A") and I want to remove all diagnosis that starts with "A105" and "B1008" that have the type "B" so in this case "A10534" will be removed?

Comment: Hi @Hellihansen, You could add another filter like this: `dt_out = dt[grep("A105|B1008", diagnosis),]
dt_out[dt_out$type != "B",]`;

Comment: This filter will just remove all types with B  - maybe I can rephrase: If I want to keep all diagnosis that starts with A105 and has type A - how can I do wo

Answer (score 2):

We can use `grepl()` here:

```r
df_out <- df[grepl("^(?:A105|B1008)", df$diagnosis), ]
```

Comment: what if I have a third varibale called type = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "A") and I want to remove all diagnosis that starts with "A105" and "B1008" that have the type "B" so in this case "A10534" will be removed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `%like%` from data.table:

```
dt[diagnosis %like% "^(A105|B1008)",]

      ID diagnosis
1:     1     A1053
2:     2    A10534
3:     1     B1008
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `startsWith`.

```
dt[startsWith(dt$diagnosis, "A105") | startsWith(dt$diagnosis, "B1008"),]
#  ID diagnosis
#1  1     A1053
#2  2    A10534
#5  5     B1008
```

Data

```
dt <- data.frame(ID = 1:5,
                 diagnosis = c("A1053", "A10534", "A1034", "A1400", "B1008"))
```

---

Benchmark

```
bench::mark(
"grep" = dt[grep("^(A105|B1008)", dt$diagnosis),],
"startsWith" = dt[startsWith(dt$diagnosis, "A105") | startsWith(dt$diagnosis, "B1008"),] )
#  expression      min  median itr/s…¹ mem_a…² gc/se…³ n_itr  n_gc total…⁴ result
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:t>   <dbl> <bch:b>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:t> <list>
#1 grep         53.5µs  59.5µs  15255.      0B    8.15  7486     4   491ms <df>  
#2 startsWith   43.7µs  48.3µs  20228.      0B   14.5   9797     7   484ms <df>
```